# Font With 256 Distinguishable Characters (For Binary Files)

Tags: fonts, web-fonts, hex, ascii

I am creating a hexadecimal binary file editor similar to https://hexed.it/. However, for my text editor, I would like to have there be a separate distinguishable character for each of the 256 hexadecimal values. So, is there a font or a character map image containing 256 that corresponds to standard ASCII characters (e.g. the 65th character corresponds to "A," the 66th character corresponds to "B," the 97th character corresponds to "a," etc.) while still each character being recogniseable purely by image. For example, this font/image-map would need to have a distinguishable difference between a regular space and a non-breaking space while still both the regular and non-breaking space looking like spaces.

Comment: Do note that their is no proper representation of *control characters* in Unicode (which is what by far all modern fonts use as encoding). That means you cannot 'display' a character with a font code of `0` or `10` or `127`. But there is a Unicode block especially designated to allow a visual representation of undisplayable characters: [Control pictures (PDF)](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2400.pdf). It even defines a code to *display* a *space*. Imagine that.

Answer (score 2):

A quick google and I found this font which seems to have been created for exactly the purpose you want.

[image]

https://github.com/dernyn/256

As the name implies all 256 characters are mapped and can be used to view NON-Printable ASCII Characters normally hidden or Ignored by default by the operating system environment and Text Editors.